# How do I disable 'swipe-right' event of ion-list in Ionic Framework?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to disable swipe-right event on the ion-list. There is a **can-swipe="true"** directive in ionic, but isn't there a directive like **can-swipe-right="false"** that would allow me to disable the swipe right event on ion-list? Here is the snippet of my code:

```
<ion-list show-delete="false" can-swipe="true">
<ion-item ng-repeat="listing in listings">
   <p>{{listing.title}}</p>
   <ion-option-button class="button-light ion-heart" ng-click="addToFavorites(listing)"></ion-option-button>
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

`can-swipe="false"` should work on ion-list but not on ion-item.

It should execute `$ionicListDelegate.canSwipeItems(false);`

FYI: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/angular/directive/list.js#L158

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jefferson. Actually, I only wanted the list to not swipe in the 'right' direction and only want the list to swipe to the left.I wanted something like can-swipe-right="false" . How do I do this? Any idea?